# how can i add local storage to my project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's last part of my project. The Local Storage.

I want to add my project local storage property, but i didnt understand supplementary resource on youtube.

i need my "user's address details" will show all time if i refresh the page. this is my project.

if you want reach the all codes you can go [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7sentyuo/1/)

thanks for all

```js
var addressList = [];

var generateGUID = () => {
    var s4 = () => {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
            .toString(16)
            .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}


var generateColumn = user => `
<div class="one" id="three">
    <h5>Adres Name</h5>
    <div>${user.name} </div>
    <button data-user="${user.id}" class="del">Del</button>
    <button data-user="${user.id}" class="edit">Edit</button>
</div>
    <h5>Addres</h5>
    <div>${user.addres} </div>
    `;

var generateRow = user => `
<div class="box" data-info='${JSON.stringify(user)}' id="${user.id}">
        <div class="one">
        <h5>Adres Name</h5>
        <div>${user.name} </div>
        <button data-user="${user.id}" class="del">Del</button>
        <button data-user="${user.id}" class="edit">Edit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
        <h5>Addres</h5>
        <div>${user.addres} </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
`;


$('#button').click(function () {

    // Kullanıcıyı oluştur.

    let user = {
        name: $('#adressName').val(),
        addres: $('#adress').val(),
        id: generateGUID()
    };

    addressList.push(user);
    $('#adressName').val('');
    $('#adress').val('');
    let row = $(generateRow(user));


    $(row).find(".del").click(function () {
        if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete?")) {
            $(row).remove();
        }
    });

    $(row).find(".edit").click(function () {
        $("#button").hide();
        $("#edit").show();
        $('#adressName').val(user.name);
        $('#adress').val(user.addres);
        $('#userId').val(user.id);

    });

    $('.asdf').append(row);

});

$('#edit').click(function () {
    let user = {
        name: $('#adressName').val(),
        addres: $('#adress').val(),
        id: $('#userId').val()
    };


    addressList.push(user);
    $('#adressName').val('');
    $('#adress').val('');
    let row = $(generateColumn(user));


    $('#' + user.id).html(generateColumn(user));
    $("#edit").hide();
    $("#button").show();

    $(".edit").click(function () {
        $("#button").show();
        $("#edit").hide();
        $('#adressName').val(user.name);
        $('#adress').val(user.addres);
        $('#userId').val(user.id);


    });


    $('#' + user.id).find(".del").click(function () {
        if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete?")) {
            $('#' + user.id).remove();
        }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't add `localStorage` - it is always there.

To store your data use:

```
localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'value');
```

To retrieve the data:

```
var myVariable = localStorage.getItem('myKey');
```

---

In your case:

```
localStorage.setItem('userAddress', user.addres);
```

Comment: i still didnt understand :( what can i do now?

Comment: @ÖmerDoğan Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mpetrov/7sentyuo/3/ .

Submit an address and refresh the page.

Comment: It is populating the address input correctly for me. Did you refresh the page after submiting? Or you need something else to happen?

Comment: you can try on fiddle. it's not work to me. i want this box(class .asdf) stay there when i refresh the page.

Comment: At this point I don't really know what you are after. It is populating and revealing the address box correctly for me everywhere I check.

Did you at least understood how to work with localStorage?